# Encrypt String with DART - FLUTTER to send SERVER (PHP)

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptojs

I need encrypt a String with a password in format SHA-512. I need the next array format to send it to the server. Can someone help me.

```
    {
   "ciphertext":"GCQIK6mmFOcfn+EtnaT3Kg==",
   "iv":"0d576b3d236d769da80cd1a4e1898d90",
   "salt":"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"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) library

eg code

```
  import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
  import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
  import 'dart:convert';
    
  void main() {
    
    var bytes = utf8.encode('woolhadotcom');    
    Digest md5Result = md5.convert(bytes);  
    Digest sha1Result = sha1.convert(bytes);    
    Digest sha224Result = sha224.convert(bytes);    
    Digest sha256Result = sha256.convert(bytes);    
    Digest sha384Result = sha384.convert(bytes);    
    Digest sha512Result = sha512.convert(bytes);  
    
    print('MD5: $md5Result');   
    print('SHA1: $sha1Result'); 
    print('SHA224: $sha224Result'); 
    print('SHA256: $sha256Result'); 
    print('SHA384: $sha384Result'); 
    print('SHA512: $sha512Result'); 
    print('SHA1 Digest bytes: ${sha1Result.bytes}');    
  }
```

Output:

```
  MD5: 0c3218227f2fdf73f7cad02389701120
  SHA1: 2335937df6a8278fb070034a2d7ca7bf12158d1e
  SHA224: be240082aec0bb79d73a663691e0ef05b011659ce8fdad215a38cd41
  SHA256: 37066049a36a44256a8014f9caf443dd2d6075ab83668c064d0b950b36206fc9  SHA384:090fbd7a7da23a0791a769123bdc580a347d624ff3b16cf03deb7a0e3c073fec9c64b3816359f1d600b46d47afd67e2d  SHA512:5c75ca70804c3ca8b21809960930b79b2e55517140803e29f52cbe98107987f614a8990b35adde08a748f5ca4cdec1efd024352e561faf47de331ae84addda11
  SHA1 Digest bytes: [35, 53, 147, 125, 246, 168, 39, 143, 176, 112, 3, 74, 45, 124, 167, 191, 18, 21, 141, 30]
```

Comment: I need the array format shown in the question. How can generate the other fields? The salt value have 512 characters.